# Bitscope DC Offset

Tags: oscilloscope

I had an old Tektronix scope for a few years that finally gave out. I recently purchased a Bitscope, but it seems to be having some problems.

I have connected the function generator to channel A, and have attempted to generated and measure a sine wave.

However, when channel A offset is set to "REF" which is described in the manual as "Zero reference voltage (i.e. no input offset)", it appears that an offset voltage does indeed appear. Please see screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNJ1D.png

As you can see, channel A offset is set to "REF", and note that the waveform generator panel shows the sine wave with zero offset, and is also set for zero offset. However, the actual measured sine wave appears to have a bit of DC offset voltage.

This tool is useless if I can't trust the measurements that it makes. Anyone have one of these and can shed some light on what I am seeing here?

Bitscope support is unresponsive.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the DC offset by grounding the probe and clicking 'Assign Input Offset'. This option is reached by right-clicking on the small circle (yellow for channel A, green for channel B) that signifies that the channel is active - to the left of where it says 'CHA' or 'CHB'. This should zero the DC reading and if you then select REF the trace should be centred.

You may need to repeat this process if you change voltage display range and for each probe individually.